# Привязка данных к DatePicker WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Возникла проблема с форматами при привязке данных к DatePicker. Необходимо отображать дату в формате dd.MM.yyyy

В конструкторе окна MainWindow прописано:

```
CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU", false);
CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("ru-RU", false);
```

Но как я понял DatePicker абсолютно игнорирует региональные настройки. Поэтому в XAML прописал вот так:

```
                    <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=DateBirth}" Width="340" Margin="8">
                        <DatePicker.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="DatePickerTextBox">
                                <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate>
                                            <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                                                     Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat={}{0:dd.MM.yyyy}, 
                                                     RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </DatePicker.Resources>
                    </DatePicker>
```

Как бы работает, но не совсем корректно. При этом возникает следующая проблема. Данные из привязанного источника данных отображаются корректно. Но если я ввожу например дату 02.06.2018 (т. е. 2 июня 2018 года) то после завершения ввода в этой дате меняются местами число и месяц и отображается в поле и записывается в привязанный источник данных уже дата 06.02.2018 (6 февраля 2018 года). Соответственно, если например ввести дату 14.07.2012, то поле подкрашивается красной рамкой (возникает ошибка System.Windows.Data Error: 7 : ConvertBack cannot convert value '14.07.2012' (type 'String'). BindingExpression:Path=SelectedDate; DataItem='DatePicker' (Name=''); target element is 'TextBox' (Name='PART_TextBox'); target property is 'Text' (type 'String') FormatException:'System.FormatException: Строка не распознана как действительное значение DateTime.
   в System.DateTimeParse.Parse(String s, DateTimeFormatInfo dtfi, DateTimeStyles styles) ... ).

Подскажите как можно решить проблему?

Comment: Написать конвертер

Comment: А можно пример как сделать? В одну сторону конвертеры писал, а вот с обратным преобразованием пока не попадалось как правильно реализовать.

Comment: XAML игнорирует текущие настройки культуры, надо задавать их явно с помощью свойства `Language`, попробуйте

Comment: Андрей, огромное спасибо. Добавил Language="ru-RU" в свойствах окна и все заработало правильно.

Comment: @АндрейNOP имхо, достойно ответа, я бы плюсанул.

Comment: @tym32167, ага, не видел, что ТС отписался, ТС, не забывайте обращаться в комментариях через `@`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Обратите внимание, на свойство `Language`, имеющееся у всех `FrameworkElement`, именно оно

> Возвращает или задает сведения о языке локализации и глобализации, который применяется к элементу.

Также, следует знать, что при вызове методов `Convert`/`ConvertBack` у конвертеров, XAML передает в них в параметре `culture` значение именно из этого свойства.

Не знаю, сделано это намеренно или по ошибке, но значение этого свойства по умолчанию всегда "en-US" и не зависит от культуры текущего потока и прочего.

Это свойство зависимостей и оно наследует значения от родительских контролов, поэтому достаточно указать `Language="ru-RU"` у окна и все контролы в окне будут использовать эти настройки.

Впрочем, если окон в проекте несколько, куда удобнее переопределить настройки один раз для всех контролов. Сделать это можно, например, где-то в конструкторе класса `App`, добавив следующий фрагмент кода:

```
FrameworkElement.LanguageProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(FrameworkElement),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(
        CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture.IetfLanguageTag)));
```