# C# WPF: Как правильно обновлять параметр <Run> из кода?

Tags: c#, wpf

Имеется `TextBlock` с фрагментами текста, имеющими разные размеры шрифта, заданные в параметре `<Run>`:

```
<TextBlock><Run FontSize="14pt">15,</Run><Run FontSize="10pt">555333</Run></TextBlock>
```

Как будет грамотно обновлять эти значения из кода?

Если указать свойство `Text`, то применится значение для всего текста и шрифт будет везде одинаковый:

```
MyTextBlock.Text = "15,555333";
```

Пробовал делать так, но при постоянном увеличении числа с последующим обновлением текста он создается заново и его приходится очищать:

```
// этот код находится в цикле
MyTextBlock.Text = null;
MyTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("15,") { FontSize = 16 });
MyTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("555333") { FontSize = 12 });
```

**Как будет правильнее обновлять данные в `TextBlock`?**

Comment: Привязки научитесь делать. У вас не должно быть создания контролов в коде вообще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не знаю, насколько это правильно, в смысле вот таким образом разбивать число, но мне метод показался самым очевидным - использовать конвертер.

Например у вас есть класс, реализующий `INotifyPropertyChanged`, на него вы настроили `DataContext` и в нем свойство, например такое.

```cs
private double _number;

public double Number
{
    get => _number;
    set
    {
        _number = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Как реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и настроить `DataContext`, я не буду рассказывать, но я раньше уже публиковал это, например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1115342/373567) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1222168/373567), можно на StackOverflow найти и множество других примеров.

Теперь можно создать вот такой класс-конвертер.

```cs
public enum DoublePart
{
    Integer, Fraction
}

public class DoubleSplitConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (value is double number && parameter is string optionText && Enum.TryParse(optionText, out DoublePart option) && Enum.IsDefined(option))
        {
            string text = number.ToString(culture);
            int index = text.IndexOf(culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator);
            switch (option)
            {
                case DoublePart.Integer:
                    return index >= 0 ? text.Remove(index) : text;
                case DoublePart.Fraction:
                    return index >= 0 ? text.Substring(index) : string.Empty;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotSupportedException("Преобразование double в обратную сторону не поддерживается");
        // здесь ничего нет, но при желании можно сделать обратную конвертацию, хотя я не представляю, зачем
    }
}
```

Код предельно прост, я думаю вы без труда сможете его прочитать

Конвертер подключить к окну просто

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <local:DoubleSplitConverter x:Key="DoubleSplitConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
```

Тогда привязка данных текстблока будет выглядеть вот так

```xml
<TextBlock>
    <Run FontSize="14pt" Text="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource DoubleSplitConverter}, ConverterParameter=Integer, ConverterCulture=RU_ru}"/><Run FontSize="10pt" Text="{Binding Number, Converter={StaticResource DoubleSplitConverter}, ConverterParameter=Fraction, ConverterCulture=RU_ru}"/>
</TextBlock>
```

Обратите внимание, что `Run` расположены в одну строку - это на самом деле важно. Если сделать перенос строки в XAML, между ними будет пробел в окне.

Кстати, если убрать `ConverterCulture=RU_ru`, будет использоваться культура по умолчанию - `EN_us`, то есть дробь будет с точкой. Культуру интерфейса по умолчанию тоже [можно изменить](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950972/218063).

Вот и всё, теперь вы можете присваивать в коде

```cs
Number = Math.PI;
```

И число будет корректно отображаться в интерфейсе. Подредактировав код конвертера можно применить необходимое форматирование.

---

Второй не менее очевидный способ реализации - сделать `UserControl` и инкапсулировать всю логику в нём, без конвертера.

Comment: Мне кажется, не обязательно приводить `parameter` к enum, wpf умеет делать это самостоятельно. Хотя, здесь параметр object же, да, тогда не получится. Сработало бы, если бы мы использовали для этого отдельное свойство в конвертере, а не параметр конвертирующей функции

Comment: А по поводу культуры есть этот ответ: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950972/218063

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо, про культуру дополнил ответ. Про `enum` уже тоже погрустил, пока код писал.

Comment: Ага, я, чтоб не грустить, использую такой подход: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/981982/218063