# Как поменять календарь на русский для стилей materialdesigninxaml?

Tags: c#, wpf

Я использую [materialdesigninxaml](http://materialdesigninxaml.net/) библиотеку для своего WPF приложения. Я не могу разобраться как настроить календарь, чтобы он отображался на русском языке и с российскими региональными настройками отображения даты. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это изменить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код XAML

```
<Window x:Class="JKXCalc.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:JKXCalc"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
     WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"
    xmlns:materialDesign="http://materialdesigninxaml.net/winfx/xaml/themes"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="500" Width="800">

<!--<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>-->

<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Label" >
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="16"/>
    </Style>

    <!--<Style x:Key="MargintStyle" TargetType="{x:Type FrameworkElement}">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="5"/>
    </Style>

    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource MargintStyle}"/>
    <Style TargetType="TextBox" BasedOn="{StaticResource MargintStyle}">
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
    </Style>
    <Style TargetType="DatePicker" BasedOn="{StaticResource MargintStyle}" >
        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="100"/>
    </Style>-->
</Window.Resources>

<Grid Margin="5 5 0 5">
    <ScrollViewer>
        <StackPanel x:Name="MainStackPanel">
            <Label Content="Калькулятор расчёта пени по коммунальным платежам" Margin="15" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" FontSize="18" FontStyle="Italic" FontFamily="Lao UI">
                <Label.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFB9B6B6" Offset="1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFE6E6E6"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Label.Background>
            </Label>
            <StackPanel Background="#FFEEEBEB" Margin="0 5 0 5">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="260"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Задолженности:" />
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelDebt" Orientation="Vertical">
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="начало просрочки"  MinWidth="100"  IsDropDownOpen="False" SelectedDateFormat="Short"  Margin="5 5 5 5" MinHeight="35"/>
                                <TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="Сумма долга" Margin="5" MinWidth="100"/>
                                <Button Content="+"  Margin="5" Width="50" Click="Button_Plus_Row_Click" Cursor="Hand" />
                                <Button Content="-"  Margin="5" Width="50" Click="Button_Click_2" Cursor="Hand" IsEnabled="False"/>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Button Content="Импорт из таблицы" Margin="5" Click="Button_ExcelLoad1"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Background="#FFEEEBEB" Margin="0 5 0 5">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="260"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Конечная дата:"/>
                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1">
                        <WrapPanel>
                            <DatePicker Name="dateFinish" materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="начало просрочки"  MinWidth="100"  IsDropDownOpen="False" SelectedDateFormat="Short"  Margin="5 5 5 5" MinHeight="35"/>
                            <Button Content="Вставить сегодня"  Margin="5" MinWidth="100" Click="Button_SetToday_Click" />
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Background="#FFEEEBEB" Margin="0 5 0 5">
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="260"/>
                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Content="Частичная оплата задолженности:" />
                    <StackPanel  Grid.Column="1" Orientation="Vertical">
                        <StackPanel x:Name="stackPanelPayment">
                            <WrapPanel>
                                <DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="дата оплаты"  MinWidth="100"  IsDropDownOpen="False" SelectedDateFormat="Short"  Margin="5 5 5 5" MinHeight="35"/>
                                <TextBox  materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="на сумму" Margin="5" MinWidth="100"/>
                                <DatePicker materialDesign:HintAssist.Hint="за месяц"  MinWidth="100"  IsDropDownOpen="False" SelectedDateFormat="Short"  Margin="5 5 5 5" MinHeight="35"/>
                                <Button Content="+"  Margin="5" Width="50" Click="Button_Plus_Row_Click" />
                                <Button Content="-"  Margin="5" Width="50" IsEnabled="False" Cursor="Hand"/>
                            </WrapPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                        <WrapPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <Button Content="Импорт из таблицы" Margin="5" Click="Button_ExcelLoad2"/>
                        </WrapPanel>
                    </StackPanel>
                </Grid>
            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="10">
                <Button Content="Рассчитать" Margin="5"/>
                <Button Content="Очистить" Margin="5"/>
            </StackPanel>

        </StackPanel>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

Comment: XAML где календарь, покажите, а то гадание по фотографиии какое-то.

Comment: <DatePicker materialDesign: <<-- тут наверное

Comment: Решение вроде тут: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48380825/cannot-set-a-specific-language-to-datepicker

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/950972/220553

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо за ссылки на решение проблемы.
Можно сделать региональные настройки глобальные, а можно локальные для каждого элемента. Я решил для каждого календаря указать локальные настройки.
Код ниже:

```
 public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        myDatePicker1.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        myDatePicker2.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        myDatePicker3.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        dateFinish.Language = XmlLanguage.GetLanguage(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.IetfLanguageTag);
        SOAPXmlCBR xmlObj = new SOAPXmlCBR();

    }
```